# 2003 SLK 230 remote key fob faulty

Tags: mercedes-benz, fob, slk230

I tried Mercedes Benz Loughton and Enfield to get me another key as thought I lost it but they said it's no longer available.

So I found it and the locksmith re soldered the circuit and chips just in case there was a break unseen, and started working after a few days.

Had the locksmith take the chips out of the existing remote and re solder them onto another key for another slk and still not working.

He said the only other thing could be the aerial in car faulty not picking up the signal.

I don't know what to do as its all done through my insurance and I cannot imagine using this lovely car with key all the time as central locking doesn't work with key. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: try looking on this site : http://www.slkworld.com/slk-r170-general-discussion/33461-can-you-re-program-key-fob.html#/topics/33461

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!